# Is it possible in a pure css?

Tags: css, gradient

I must do background in my site exactly like this:

Is it possible in a pure css? I have inspect mode in a invision, and I can read that it's

But when I add this code to my css, effect is different. Here I can see eclipse line, and I don't know how get this effect in pure css.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: try adding `blur` effect

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try Blur effect it might work for you

```css
.blur {
  background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1486723312829-f32b4a25211b?dpr=2&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&h=1000&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=&bg=') no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
  filter: blur(13px);
  position: absolute;
  height: 300px;
  top: -50px;
  left: -50px;
  right: -50px;
  bottom: -50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="blur"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try something like this:

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

div.background {
  height: 80%;
  width: 80%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: #eee;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="background"></div>
</div>
```

Play with background color and size of the background div to fit your needs.